# Highcharts's x - axis (datetime) format

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am making graphs using js. The data is fetched using php, The x-axis is the timestamp (ex 2018.01.22.18 (the format is year.month.day.hour.minute)), and the y-axis is the temperature.

I am plotting several lines rather than a single line. However, the corresponding timestamp must fit the x-axis, which is not the case. (The timestamp of each data is different.)

It is also expected that the highcharts do not match this format, so the graphs are output in the order in which they are placed in the array. I want the timestamp of the data to be exactly on the x-axis.

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: When supplying code/text data, please provide it as text. Images are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search engines, and make it harder for readers to help you. Would you fix this now to prevent your question from closing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you have to convert it to timestamp, you can do this in PHP or in Javascript :

**Javascript example :**

```js
// you date
var myDate="2018.01.22.18.00";
myDate=myDate.split(".");

// build new js date object
var newDate=myDate[1]+"-"+myDate[2]+"-"+myDate[0]+" "+myDate[3]+":"+myDate[4];

// return the timestamp
console.log(new Date(newDate).getTime()); //will display 1516633200000
```

**The complete code will be something like this :**

```js
// your initiale data array
var data = [
["2018.01.01.18.00", 1.1, 4.7],
["2018.01.02.18.00", 1.8, 6.4],
["2018.01.03.18.00", 1.7, 6.9],
["2018.01.04.18.00", 2.6, 7.4],
["2018.01.05.18.00", 3.3, 9.3],
["2018.01.06.18.00", 3.0, 7.9],
["2018.01.07.18.00", 3.9, 6.0]
]
// convert to timestamp
var timestampData = new Array(data.length);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // your date
 myDate=data[i][0].split(".");

 // build new js date object
    var myNewDate = new Date(myDate[1]+"-"+myDate[2]+"-"+myDate[0]+" "+myDate[3]+":"+myDate[4]);
 timestampData[i] = new Array(myNewDate.getTime() , data[i][1] , data[i][2]);
}

// Create the chart

Highcharts.chart('container', {

        chart: {
            type: 'arearange',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperatures',
            data: timestampData
        }]

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: How can I give this format to the highcharts option?

Comment: I updated the answer with the complete example, hope its helps ;)

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot and I was able to get a final conclusion. Thank you.
Have a good day

Comment: So happy to help you have nice day